# How can I create a cookie in Razor Pages when a button is pressed in the _Layout file?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

I am new to Razor pages and am having trouble figuring this out without controllers. I understand typically if this was a regular razor page, I could just add an OnPost method to the PageModel, but with _Layout, my understanding is there shouldn't be a PageModel, as it will conflict with the PageModel being called with `@RenderBody()`

I want to do something like this:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> @ViewData["Title"] </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <partial name="_TopNavigation" />
        <div>
            <button type="button" asp-page-handler="Dismissed"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div>
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When button is pressed, I want to add a server side cookie. Something like this:

addCookie.cs :

```
public IActionResult onPostDismissed()
{
    Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "value1", cookieOptions);
}
```

I want the button to be on every page, which is why I have added it to _Layout, however I haven't been able to figure out where I can add code to handle that. Also, I know this would be fairly simple with javascript, but I specifically want to set the cookie server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call the handler method in the layout page. I suggest you could try to create a new razor page with its handler to add the response cookie.

Then you could set the form's asp-page attribute in the page to let the button call that handler method.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Add below codes into layout page:

```
<form method="post" asp-page="/Dismissed">
    <button type="submit" value="Click">Click Me To Add Cookie</button>
</form>
```

Create a new razor page called Dismissed and add below codes into its page model

```
    public void OnPost() {

        int i = 0;
        Response.Cookies.Append("MyCookie", "value1");

    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That worked! I didn't even know you could add a page handler to a form. If you remove the breakpoint, and click the button, it will redirect you to the /dismissed page. Is there a way to set it not to redirect when you click the button?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out you can add a hidden input to the form and pass the current Url to the function and do a localRedirect to that url.